# Puppet service not notified

Tags: vagrant, puppet, provisioning

I'm trying to provision a centos host with vagrant using puppet with php-fpm and my own configuration. I followed the guide on https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/restart-a-service-when-a-file-changes.html but it doesn't seem to work.

Expected result: the php-fpm service runs using my configuration.

Actual result: the php-fpm service runs using the default configuration.

```
# This class represents the php-fpm PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
class php56fpm {

  package { 'php-fpm':
    ensure  => 'present',
    name    => 'php56u-fpm',
    require => Yumrepo['IUS']
  }

  service { 'php-fpm':
    ensure  => 'running',
    name    => 'php-fpm',
    enable  => true,
    require => Package['php-fpm']
  }

  file { '/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf':
    ensure  => present,
    mode    => '0644',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/php56fpm/www.conf',
    require => Package['php-fpm'],
    notify  => Service['php-fpm']
  }

}
```

Relevant piece of the debug log:

```
macbook$ vagrant up website-dev
Bringing machine 'website-dev' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
-- <OUTPUT OMMITTED BECAUSE OF STACKOVERFLOW LIMIT> --
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Environment/File[/etc/environment]/before: requires File_line[LANG]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Environment/File_line[LANG]/before: requires File_line[LC_ALL]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[htop]/require: requires Package[epel-release]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Package[nginx]/require: requires Yumrepo[epel]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]/require: requires Package[nginx]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Service[nginx]/require: requires Package[nginx]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpcommon]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.ini]/require: requires Package[phpcommon]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpopcache]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpgd]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpintl]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmemcache]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmbstring]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmysql]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmcrypt]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpxml]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Package[php-fpm]/require: requires Yumrepo[IUS]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/File[/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf]/require: requires Package[php-fpm]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Service[php-fpm]/require: requires Package[php-fpm]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Service[php-fpm]/require: requires File[/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Environment/File_line[LC_ALL]: Autorequiring File[/etc/environment]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html]: Autorequiring File[/usr/share/nginx/html]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html]: Autorequiring File[/usr/share/nginx/html]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html]: Autorequiring File[/usr/share/nginx/html]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png]: Autorequiring File[/usr/share/nginx/html]
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png]: Autorequiring File[/usr/share/nginx/html]
==> website-dev: Info: Applying configuration version '1494423596'
==> website-dev: Debug: Prefetching yum resources for package
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -qa --nosignature --nodigest --qf '%{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n''
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q epel-release --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list epel-release'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[epel-release](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install epel-release'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[epel-release]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[epel-release]: The container Class[Admintools] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q htop --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list htop'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[htop](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install htop'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[htop]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[htop]: The container Class[Admintools] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Environment/File_line[LANG]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Environment/File_line[LANG]: The container Class[Environment] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Environment/File_line[LC_ALL]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Environment/File_line[LC_ALL]: The container Class[Environment] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Environment]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Prefetching inifile resources for yumrepo
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]/descr: descr changed 'Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch' to 'Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]/baseurl: defined 'baseurl' as 'https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]/repo_gpgcheck: defined 'repo_gpgcheck' as '0'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]/gpgkey: gpgkey changed 'file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7' to 'https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]: The container Class[Yumrepos] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]: The container Class[Yumrepos] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]: The container Class[Yumrepos] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[epel]: The container Class[Yumrepos] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[IUS]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Info: changing mode of /etc/yum.repos.d/IUS.repo from 600 to 644
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Yumrepos/Yumrepo[IUS]: The container Class[Yumrepos] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Yumrepos]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-fpm --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-fpm'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[php-fpm](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-fpm'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Package[php-fpm]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Package[php-fpm]: The container Class[Php56fpm] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/File[/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf]: Filebucketed /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf to puppet with sum e0578952b10d49673609a6c26819cbae
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/File[/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}e0578952b10d49673609a6c26819cbae' to '{md5}a641cb01a9e52be58ac10446788df0ef'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/File[/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf]: The container Class[Php56fpm] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl is-active php-fpm'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl is-enabled php-fpm'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl start php-fpm'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl is-enabled php-fpm'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl enable php-fpm'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Service[php-fpm]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Service[php-fpm]: The container Class[Php56fpm] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Php56fpm/Service[php-fpm]: Unscheduling refresh on Service[php-fpm]
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Php56fpm]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Exec[setenforce Permissive](provider=posix): Executing 'setenforce Permissive'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing 'setenforce Permissive'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Selinux/Exec[setenforce Permissive]/returns: executed successfully
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Selinux/Exec[setenforce Permissive]: The container Class[Selinux] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Selinux]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q nginx --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list nginx'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[nginx](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install nginx'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Package[nginx]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Package[nginx]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]: Filebucketed /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to puppet with sum 93bc8e01bfd45e7e18b23acc178ae25b
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}93bc8e01bfd45e7e18b23acc178ae25b' to '{md5}bb66265555761468ac2b90f6f5fc0616'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]/group: group changed 'root' to 'vagrant'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl is-active nginx'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl is-enabled nginx'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl start nginx'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl is-enabled nginx'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/systemctl enable nginx'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Service[nginx]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Service[nginx]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Service[nginx]: Unscheduling refresh on Service[nginx]
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png]: Filebucketed /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png to puppet with sum 425a3bef572ffa7e706bd7db8452c733
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png]: Removing existing file for replacement with absent
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png]/ensure: removed
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-logo.png]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html]: Filebucketed /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html to puppet with sum 2c3ce75d2f64b4c84a164aeae91a98d5
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html]: Removing existing file for replacement with absent
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html]/ensure: removed
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html]: Filebucketed /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html to puppet with sum 0723e124f290ef0c356627361c46b792
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html]: Removing existing file for replacement with absent
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html]/ensure: removed
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html]: Filebucketed /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html to puppet with sum 9a3e19f24fe322a35f4978dd3d55fe91
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html]: Removing existing file for replacement with absent
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html]/ensure: removed
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png]: Filebucketed /usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png to puppet with sum cb3b06ec4e9db0a28bd70f6eba16d449
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png]: Removing existing file for replacement with absent
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png]/ensure: removed
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/usr/share/nginx/html/poweredby.png]: The container Class[Nginx] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Nginx]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-mbstring --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-mbstring'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpmbstring](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-mbstring'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmbstring]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmbstring]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-opcache --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-opcache'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpopcache](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-opcache'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpopcache]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpopcache]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-mcrypt --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-mcrypt'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpmcrypt](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-mcrypt'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmcrypt]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmcrypt]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-common --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /etc/php.ini
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.ini]: Filebucketed /etc/php.ini to puppet with sum 375424803c2578ef3a9b50ab70e9ddc1
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.ini]/content: content changed '{md5}375424803c2578ef3a9b50ab70e9ddc1' to '{md5}1fae991d2164a2d4f92b7ed1fc0c1097'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.ini]/group: group changed 'root' to 'vagrant'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.ini]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.ini]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-pecl-memcache --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-pecl-memcache'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpmemcache](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-pecl-memcache'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmemcache]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmemcache]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-gd --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-gd'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpgd](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-gd'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpgd]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpgd]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-intl --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-intl'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpintl](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-intl'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpintl]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpintl]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Info: Computing checksum on file /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini
==> website-dev: Info: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini]: Filebucketed /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini to puppet with sum 062813b730e0f63ec3dd58e4fc30d44b
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini]/content: content changed '{md5}062813b730e0f63ec3dd58e4fc30d44b' to '{md5}1e58a98322e25225d5fcb145979b2fa9'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini]/group: group changed 'root' to 'vagrant'
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/File[/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-xml --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q php56u-mysqlnd --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php56u-mysqlnd'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[phpmysql](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56u-mysqlnd'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmysql]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Php56/Package[phpmysql]: The container Class[Php56] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q mlocate --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list mlocate'
==> website-dev: Debug: Package[mlocate](provider=yum): Ensuring => present
==> website-dev: Debug: Executing '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install mlocate'
==> website-dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[mlocate]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: /Stage[main]/Admintools/Package[mlocate]: The container Class[Admintools] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Admintools]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Class[Php56]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
==> website-dev: Debug: Finishing transaction 43939220
==> website-dev: Debug: Storing state
==> website-dev: Info: Creating state file /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml
==> website-dev: Debug: Stored state in 0.00 seconds
==> website-dev: Notice: Finished catalog run in 38.63 seconds
==> website-dev: Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rrddir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/rrd", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
==> website-dev: Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]/seluser: Found seluser default 'system_u' for /var/lib/puppet/rrd
==> website-dev: Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]/selrole: Found selrole default 'object_r' for /var/lib/puppet/rrd
==> website-dev: Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]/seltype: Found seltype default 'puppet_var_lib_t' for /var/lib/puppet/rrd
==> website-dev: Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]/selrange: Found selrange default 's0' for /var/lib/puppet/rrd
==> website-dev: Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]/ensure: created
==> website-dev: Debug: Finishing transaction 37522140
==> website-dev: Debug: Received report to process from dev.example.com
==> website-dev: Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
==> website-dev: Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
==> website-dev: Debug: Processing report from dev.example.com with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
==> website-dev: Configuring cache buckets...
```

I also tried changing the `require => Package['php-fpm']` to `require => Service['php-fpm']` in the `file` resource but that results in a dependency cycle.

Comment: The log excerpt you present is *a* relevant piece, in the sense that it appears to confirm that the resource relationships are recognized, but it is not the part that seems most relevant to me.  I would be interested in seeing the part of the log that shows the actual application (or non-application) of these resources, from a run in which a modified version of `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` is applied.

Comment: Overall, the manifest looks good to me, so I'm inclined to suspect that the situation is not as you perceive it to be.

Comment: Agree. The actual log of catalog application is probably going to be rather revealing here.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't respond earlier but I was not allowed to work any further on this issue at work. But thanks for thinking with me! I've just added a larger log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem; it was the old php configuration that was used, not the php-fpm configuration. The issue was that the php-fpm package was installed before the php package so I needed to add `require php56` to the class.